# Deploy telegram бота на heroku

Tags: java, telegram-bot, развертывание, heroku

Коллеги, написал телеграм бота и хочу развернуть его на heroku, что нужно прописать в ProcFile? Проект написан на Java как консольное приложение.

Comment: а разве хероку стал поддерживать сишарп?

Comment: @Anatol изменил на java.

Answer (score 1):

1. **artifacts** - в проекте должна быть соответствующая папка, содержащая файлы:

   - webapp-runner.jar
   - project-name.jar
2. **Procfile**

   ```
   web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar artifacts/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT artifacts/project-name.jar
   ```
3. **pom.xml**

   ```
   . . .
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>copy</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <artifactItems>
                       <artifactItem>
                           <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                           <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                           <version>8.5.11.2</version>
                           <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                       </artifactItem>
                   </artifactItems>
                   <outputDirectory>artifacts</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   . . .
   ```

Answer (score 0):

можно и так:
в

> pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
           ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass> //тут пишем свой main class
                            <name>name</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

в `Procfile` пишем `web: sh target/bin/name`
либо `worker: sh target/bin/name`
затем в `git` пишем команду `heroku ps:scale web=1` / ... `worker=1`